# Super key shortcuts "unresponsive" when configured via Custom Shortcuts

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys, ccsm

When I set custom shortcuts from **Keyboard / Shortcuts / Custom Shortcuts**, all of the ones set to use Super key (e.g. <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, set to open a text file using the default text editor) have a weird threshold between key presses. If Super is released too quickly, the shortcut is not registered. In practice, it requires, what I would call, an abnormally long press.

If I set up exactly same keys via **Commands** plugin in **Compiz**, the unresponsiveness is gone. What causes this behaviour? Can the the "threshold" be changed from somewhere? Does this happen on purpose - to give priority to the default Super key shortcuts in Unity?

Additional information:

- Ubuntu 12.10
- Seems to affect only Super key (at least I have not noticed the same on other keys)
- Super key is not assigned to show the launcher (I've changed it to Super + A, but it seems to make no difference whether Super is used)
- The command or key combination does not matter, except possibly if additionally Ctrl, Shift or Alt are used (e.g. Ctrl+Super+1), but I am not 100% sure about this, because it is hard to test this consistently as the difference is only in milliseconds

I *do not* want use **Compiz / Commands**, because the plugin only allows 20 commands (why is there such restriction in the first place?!) and setting up them in there is much more troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it and it seems like <kbd>Super</kbd> will have preference always, so just add <kbd>Alt</kbd> to your **Custom Shortcuts** and you should be sorted.

Comment: I wouldn't want to do that, as pressing Super+Alt+<n> is considerably harder and I'm already using Ctrl and Alt for additional shortcuts. (If you meant using only Alt, that's a non-starter as many applications use Alt+<n> by default...).

Comment: Actually, I don't kwow where your Alt key is, but from what I know it's right next to Super (mind you, I've only used 3 different languages generic keyboards so far). Usually I can do Alt+Super with _folded thumb_ technique, or _folded thumb+crooked pimkie_ ;) That's why I propose this solution.

Comment: It is right next to Super, but I just find it harder (small fingers I guess), especially when using letter or number keys further away. (No idea what "crooked pimkie" means :P)